# Buddhist Therapists?

Tags: lay-buddhism, psychology, lay-practices

I'm looking for Buddhist therapists for a friend of mine (who is also a practicing Buddhist). He's been using traditional therapists and it has not worked for him

Is there a list of Buddhist therapists available anywhere online?

Answer (score 2):

*For the United States* there is a great resource: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/buddhist

For the UK: https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/counselling/buddhist

After filtering for location it's possible to add many other filters, for example for types of therapy (CBT, ACT, MBSR, etc)

---

It's also possible to change the country in the upper right of the page

It seems that in general you first need to filter by area and can then add filters. "Buddhist" is one of the filters which can be found under the "more..." button in the "faith" column

---

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking a health professional such as a psychiatrist or a clinical psychologist can not let his or or her buddhisms come into play in their practice.

They can not be expected deviate much from what they are taught in school because that is a quick way to lose the license.